# How to fetch the first 2 or 3 rows from Mysql DB using Mysql PHP function?

Tags: php, mysql

How to fetch the first two rows from Mysql DB using Mysql PHP function? Is there any function which can give me first 2 or 3 rows from the select query we fired?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `LIMIT`. From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html),  to retrieve 3 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 3;
```

Or to retrieve rows 6-15:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;
```

For this query (i.e. with no constraint) if you are not using an `ORDER BY` clause your results will be ordered as they appear in the database.

Comment: I think I am gone out of my mind...I dont believe this that I asked this question...Thanks Mate for the reply and alerting me that I am tired.....

Comment: Thanks Again for the condolence :)

Comment: If you are not using an ORDER BY clause your results will be ordered **ran-dom-ly**.

Comment: Orrite, I did that before asking this Blunder :)

Comment: @ the belligerent Colonel: do you have any **ref-er-en-ces**? I tend to find `LIMIT 3` gives me the first three rows that I see from `SELECT * FROM tbl`. If they were random why would one search for the most optimised manner in which to randomise results? http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **[`limit`](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)** clause in your query:

```
select * from your_table limit 3
```

This will select the **first** three rows.

And:

```
select * from your_table limit 5, 3
```

The later will select rows starting from 5 and return three rows.

Comment: Thanks Sarfraz for the detailing

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Fire a query to select **all** the rows
   and then select 2 or 3 rows as
   needed using `PHP`.
2. Fire a query to select only the
   necessary number of rows using `LIMIT`
   clause.

The 2nd option is preferable.

Comment: Thanks unicornaddict for the "Points to Remember Style" will keep in mind :)